# actionPerformed confusion on button events

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am trying to make a game in java, when a button is pressed I want it to change icon to indicate that button has been selected, then when it is clicked again I want to change it to its original icon to show it has been deselected.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == b[7][4] && selected == false)
    {
        b[7][4].setIcon(selected);
        selected = true;
    }

    if(e.getSource() == b[7][4] && selected == true)
    {
        b[7][4].setIcon(king);
        selected = false;           
    }
}
```

This code currently does as I wish but it runs both at the same time thus changes the icon and then immediately changes it back to the original icon. How can I make it so one click changes it to `selected` and then the second click changes it back to a `king` icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `else` before the next `if` to chain them:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == b[7][4] && selected == false)
    {
        b[7][4].setIcon(selected);
        selected = true;
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == b[7][4] && selected == true)
    {
        b[7][4].setIcon(king);
        selected = false;           
    }
}
```

This way the second `if` clause is only checked if the first condition evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution: use a JToggleButton and set its Icon and its selectedIcon via `setIcon(...)` and `setSelectedIcon(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider condensing your code into a single `setIcon()` call:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource() == b[7][4]) {
        b[7][4].setIcon(selected ? king : defau1t);
        selected = !selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the ? do here?

Comment: @hysteriaistic It's a short cutted `if-else` statement, known as a ternary statement

Comment: Oh that's a ternary operator `?:`. It's a compact `if..else`, saying if `selected` is `true` then use the `king` icon, else if selected is `false` then use the `defau1t` icon.